# How to Change OrientDb Studio port

Tags: orientdb

I'm testing OrientDb 3 and I need to change the port for the OrientDb Studio. Is this posible?

Running OrientDb 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

You can change the port value in the `orientdb-server-config.xml` file

```
 <listener protocol="binary" socket="default" port-range="2424-2430" ip-address="0.0.0.0"/>
 <listener protocol="http" socket="default" port-range="2480-2490" ip-address="0.0.0.0">
```

and then start the server

Hope it helps

Regards